# Как получить данные из json при помощи ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, long-polling

Пытаюсь реализовать Ajax Long polling в своем проекте вот скрин структуры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако Хром выдает вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перепробовал кучу вариантов. Инфу в инете не нашел. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var poll = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'status.json',
            dataType:'json',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.two)
             }
            // statusCode: {
            //     404: function() {
            //         console.log( "page not found" );
            //     }
            // }
        })
    };
    poll();
    setInterval(function () {
        poll();
    }, 2000);
})();
```

Comment: вам на java или на javascript?

Comment: покажите ваш код запроса

Comment: Добавил сверху.Код нужен именно на javascript.

Comment: Тогда при чем тут Java ??

Comment: Если не учитывать что это Java проект и весь сервер на ней, то вообще ни при чем.